# facebook API get feeds

Tags: facebook

Hello i'm working for a while in opengraph but there is something that keeps bugging me.

I cant get the messages from every person in feed

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "984656456_1111111", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Xxx Some  Name", 
        "id": "478975485"
      }, 
      "message": "test", 
      "picture": "https://somepictureSomewhere.jpg", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151943257604861&set=p.101519&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
      "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/589884/posts/10151943984861"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "value": ""
      }, 
      "type": "photo", 
      "status_type": "added_photos", 
      "object_id": "1015194324861", 
      "created_time": "2013-10-24T12:54:43+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2013-10-24T12:54:43+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/58980/feed?limit=25&since=1382619283", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/58988/feed?limit=25&until=1382619282"
  }
}
```

This is my code, 
I get the following error:  RuntimeBinder exception was unhandeled with the usersFeeds.message[i]
While UsersFeeds.data[i].from.name is working fine.

```
  FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                dynamic UsersFeeds = fb.Get("/me/posts");
                int teller = (int)Usersfriends.data.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    lstUsersFriends.Items.Add(UsersFeeds.data[i].from.name);
                    lstUsersFriends.Items.Add(UsersFeeds.message[i]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your iterations be based on count?

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
dynamic UsersFeeds = fb.Get("/me/posts");
int teller = (int)Usersfriends.data.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < **teller**; i++)
{
    lstUsersFriends.Items.Add(UsersFeeds.data[i].from.name);
    lstUsersFriends.Items.Add(UsersFeeds.message[i]);
}
```